# Execute storedprocedure that return 0 with entitiy-framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my db that looks like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1)
BEGIN
    -- select statement
END
```

I am using this procedure to check if there is any data inside table1. Table1 is used as a queue on database side.

In my C# application I am using the entity framework to execute this stored procedure. Method Looks like this:

```
using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var result = db.ALL_GET_JOBS();

            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No new jobs");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("received {0} new jobs", result.Count()));
            }
        }
```

When I execute to procedure I get an exception telling me that one of my defined columns doesn't exists within the result. Yeah, because the procedure is returning 0. The exception is thrown before I reach the if statement.

I already tried adding .DefaultIfEmpty(null) or .FirstOrDefault() to the call of the procedure, but as far as I can say, the error occurs during the evaluation of the result.

Does any one of you have an idea how to handle a procedure that is returning 0 instead of a result set in entity Framework?

bg
Christoph

Comment: Do you have an explicit `RETURN 0` statement in your procedure, or it simply doesn't do anything if the table is empty?

Comment: I also tried an explicit return 0. Also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your sp or create a new one with Count function:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1
```

with this your resul is always a number (0 or greater).

Comment: The idea behind the function was not to really ask for data if nothing is inside the table and if there is any to return them. I also tried to change the function to return 0 in the else branch. Same Problem as with the already used one. What you imply is to create a procedure to check if data exists. If there is any, call another procedure to get the actual data. Or didn’t I catch you right?

Comment: @Christoph-yes ,you noticed well,my suggestion was having two stored procedures: first for existence, second for all data if it is required.

Comment: @Christoph Or just remove IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1) from your SP.I think the culprit is IF statement in your sp

Comment: After talking to our database engineer we decided to get rid of the if Statement.

Answer (score 0):

I konw it's a workaround, but have you tried having the stored procedure always return the same?

Something like:

SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1

You can just check if **result.Count() == 0** instead of **result == null**.